# Displaying avg reading in seven days interval

Tags: php

Given an array and I need to to display the average after every seventh row

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 01-03-2015
            [site_id] => 1
            [starting_reading] => 567
            [close_reading] => 567
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 03-03-2015
        [site_id] => 1
        [starting_reading] => 567
        [close_reading] => 567

    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 08-03-2015
        [site_id] => 1
        [starting_reading] => 567
        [close_reading] => 567

    )
)
```

Now what i need, is to  display all avg reading in 7 days like:

```
1 to 7 
--------------------- avg=close-start----------
8 to 14
--------------------- avg=close-start----------
15 to 21
--------------------- avg=close-start----------
22 to 28
--------------------- avg=close-start----------
29 to 31 
--------------------- avg=close-start----------
```

date        starting_reading    close_reading

01-03-2015

03-03-2015

--------------------- avg=close-start----------

08-03-2015

--------------------- avg=close-start----------

Comment: you can start using `foreach`

Comment: yes i did using foreach but unable to display avg in every seventh day of month. as i find dates in array.i am able to display for every seventh data but i need to display date between 1 to 7, 8-14 so on

Answer (score 0):

```
//$arr is as the array you described
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
  //$k will be some integer 0...count($arr)-1 assuming a 'normal' index
  //$v is your child array, where you can access attributes such as $v['date']
  //every seventh row can be done in a number of ways, the easiest way is:
  if($k % 7 == 0){
    //then show new line. This will happen every time the number divides into seven. 0, 7, 14, 21... etc.
    var_dump($v); will output your child of the seventh (multiple) item
  }
}
```

Including your example for dates and averages assuming array is correctly formatted

```
//$arr is as the array you described
$close = 0;
$start = 0;
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
  //$k will be some integer 0...count($arr)-1 assuming a 'normal' index
  //$v is your child array, where you can access attributes such as $v['date']
  //every seventh row can be done in a number of ways, the easiest way is:
  if($k % 7 == 0){
    $close = 0; //reset close
    $start = 0; //reset start
  }
  $close += (int)$v['close_reading'];
  $start += (int)$v['starting_reading'];
  if(($k + 1) % 7 == 0){ //this is the last row, 6, 13, 20 etc.
    echo ($k-5).' to '.($k+1);
    echo 'Average: '.(($close - $start) / 7);
  }
}
```

Comment: what if i dont have  seven days. it is not necessary there will exact 7 enties in array to check mod of 7

Comment: it was assuming a seven days average, if not seventh day wait for more data. more of an example to be tweaked to required use case

Comment: thanks for your help  as above example i have three dates 1,3 and 8 ,i have to display 1 ,3 and avg and there are no dates before 8  i have displayed avg after 8th